# Ansible bitbucket clone provisioning ssh error

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ansible, bitbucket, vagrant-provision

In summary, When provisioning my vagrant box using Ansible, I get thrown a mysterious error when trying to clone my bitbucket private repo using ssh.
The error states that the "Host key verification failed".

Yet if I vagrant ssh and then run the '*git clone*' command, the private repo is successfully cloned. This indicates that the ssh forward agent is indeed working and the vagrant box can access my private key associated with the bitbucket repo.

I have been struggling for two days on this issue and am loosing my mind!
Please, somebody help me!!!

**Vagrantfile:**

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
    
  # Only contains ansible dependencies
  config.vm.provision "shell",
    inline: "sudo apt-get install python-minimal -y"

  # Use ansible for all provisioning:
  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "provisioning/playbook.yml"
  end

end
```

My **playbook.yml** is as follows:

```
---

- hosts: all
  become: true

  tasks:
    - name: create /var/www/ directory
      file: dest=/var/www/ state=directory owner=www-data group=www-data mode=0755

    - name: Add the user 'ubuntu' to group 'www-data'
      user:
        name: ubuntu
        shell: /bin/bash
        groups: www-data
        append: yes
      
    - name: Clone bitbucket repo
      git:
        repo: git@bitbucket.org:gustavmahler/example.com.git
        dest: /var/www/poo
        version: master
        accept_hostkey: yes
```

**Error Message:**

`vagrant provision`

> TASK [common : Clone bitbucket repo] *******************************************
>
> fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/git clone --origin origin '' /var/www/poo", "failed": true, "msg": "Cloning into '/var/www/poo'...\nWarning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '104.192.143.3' to the list of known hosts.\r\nPermission denied (publickey).\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.", "rc": 128, "stderr": "Cloning into '/var/www/poo'...\nWarning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '104.192.143.3' to the list of known hosts.\r\nPermission denied (publickey).\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.\n", "stderr_lines": ["Cloning into '/var/www/poo'...", "Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '104.192.143.3' to the list of known hosts.", "Permission denied (publickey).", "fatal: Could not read from remote repository.", "", "Please make sure you have the correct access rights", "and the repository exists."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

**Additional Info:**

- *ssh-add -l* on my machine does contain the associated bitbucket repo key.
- *ssh-add -l* inside the vagrant box does also contain the associated bitbucket repo key (through ssh-forwarding).

**Yet cloning works** if done manually inside the vagrant box **?**:

```
vagrant ssh
git clone git@bitbucket.org:myusername/myprivaterepo.com.git
Then type "yes" to allow the RSA fingerprint to be added to ~/.ssh/known_hosts (as its first connection with bitbucket)
```

**Possible solution?**

I have seen in the Ansible documentation that there is a *[key_file](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/git_module.html#options):* option. How would I reference the private key which is located outside the vagrant box and is passed in using ssh forwarding?

I do have multiple ssh keys for different entities inside my ~/.ssh/ Perhaps the git clone command when run by Ansible provisioning isn't selecting the correct key?

Any help is greatly appreciated and thanks for reading my nightmare.

Comment: Please see my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47784489/ansible-bitbucket-clone-repo-provisioning-ssh-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you run the whole playbook with `become: true`, SSH key-forwarding (as well as troubleshooting) becomes irrelevant, because the user connecting to BitBucket from your play is `root`.

Run the task connecting to BitBucket as `ubuntu` user:

- either specifying `become: false` in the `Clone bitbucket repo` task),
- or removing `become: true` From the play and adding it only to tasks that require elevated permissions.

Answer (score 1):

This answer comes direct from techraf's helpful comments.

- I changed the owner of the /var/www directory from 'www-data' to
  'ubuntu' (the username I use to login via ssh).
- I also added "become: false" above the git task.

NOTE: I have since been dealing with the following issue so this answer does not fully resolve my problems:
[Ansible bitbucket clone repo provisioning ssh error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47784489/ansible-bitbucket-clone-repo-provisioning-ssh-error)

**Updated working playbook.yml file**:

```
---

- hosts: all
  become: true

  tasks:
    - name: create /var/www/ directory
      file: dest=/var/www/ state=directory owner=ubuntu group=www-data mode=0755

    - name: Add the user 'ubuntu' to group 'www-data'
      user:
        name: ubuntu
        shell: /bin/bash
        groups: www-data
        append: yes

    - name: Clone bitbucket repo
      become: false
      git:
        repo: git@bitbucket.org:[username]/example.com.git
        dest: /var/www/poo
        version: master
        accept_hostkey: yes
```