# Docker mounted volume of Influxdb is owned by root

Tags: docker, influxdb, file-ownership, mounted-volumes

I am running Influxdb image with mounted volume like this:

```
docker run -v $(pwd)/data:/var/lib/influxdb influxdb
```

This will create `data/` directory owned by root:

```
$ ls -ld data/
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jun 10 10:47 data/
```

I can not find out **how to mount volume under common user**. It is not possible to move the directory unless logged in as root. I know I can *chown* the directory and I've found [Docker container creating directories owned by root, I need them owned by 1000:1000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50317119/docker-container-creating-directories-owned-by-root-i-need-them-owned-by-10001), but I would like to know if Influxdb image can handle it on its own?

If I run it as current user:

```
docker run --user=$UID -v $(pwd)/data/:/var/lib/influxdb influxdb
```

I end up with:

```
run: create server: mkdir all: mkdir /var/lib/influxdb/meta: permission denied
```

Comment: In short, NO. The official docker image install and run influxdb within `root` user, unless you will create your own Dockerfile, build your own image with the exact same UID/GID as your host user. Otherwise, you will always have trouble to access/migrate data. Beside that, I think you can consider use named volume instead of mount host directory, see the [Backup, restore, or migrate data volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes).

Comment: @Dai Thanks for info regarding named volumes and backup. The main reason why I use mounted directory is the backup of data.